# Assays for detecting RNA binding with protein

Tags: proteins, rna

In a project I'm working on, we are designing a system where specific RNAs bind to proteins - an important part of this is to test whether the RNA binds when we modify the proteins in some way. What assays are there to test whether a specific (or non-specific) RNA is binding to a protein?

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend an [electrophoretic mobility shift assay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophoretic_mobility_shift_assay) (EMSA), one procedure for which can be found [here](https://www.thermofisher.com/ca/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/methods-detecting-protein-rna-interactions.html).